# Analysing dataset with unicode characters with different encodings give strange results

Tags: python, unicode, encoding

I am trying to analyse names from a dataset that uses different (mixed) encodings within the dataset. It contains place names, among much other geospatial data. After running the script, I get a list of place names matching geo-locations, i.e. `[u'BR', u'BR-ES', u'BRA', u'Brasil', u'Brazil', u'ES', u'Espirito Santo', u'Esp\xedrito Santo', u'Federative Republic of Brazil', u'Guarapari', u'Rep\xfablica Federativa do Brasil', u'gpxupload.py']`. So far all good. But sometimes the dataset give me results such as `u'Taubat\u0102\u0160'` which in the analyzation is treated as `TaubatĂŠ` instead of the correct value `Taubaté`, the previous example produces `Espírito Santo` and `Republic Federative do Brasil`

Is there a way to capture `\u0102\u0160` and converts it to `\xe9` without having to create individual `.replace()` rules for each letter?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`u'Taubat\u0102\u0160'` was decoded with the wrong codec.  It was actually UTF-8, but decoded as 'iso-8859-2'.  Ideally, decode it correctly in the first place, but the following backs out the error:

```
>>> u'Taubat\u0102\u0160'.encode('iso-8859-2').decode('utf8')
u'Taubat\xe9'
>>> print(u'Taubat\u0102\u0160'.encode('iso-8859-2').decode('utf8'))
Taubaté
```

Comment: I tried your example, but it seems like it doesn't work, since the input looks like it is of mixed encoding: `Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "./gpxtest.py", line 619, in get_relation
    return result.encode('iso-8859-2').decode('utf8')
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/encodings/iso8859_2.py", line 12, in encode
    return codecs.charmap_encode(input,errors,encoding_table)
UnicodeEncodeError: 'charmap' codec can't encode characters in position 830-837: character maps to <undefined>`

Comment: If you have mixed encodings, and don't know what they are, you have a bigger problem.

Comment: I am currently trying a `clean(string)` function that tries `string.encode('encoding').decode('utf8')` against different encodings. Currently seems to work, though it will take a few hours with testing.